# IP range whitelist for Google cloud IAP in premise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-on-prem-howto

The docs there give a way to whitelist IP addresses to check that auth has been performed. However a range of IPs is not specified.

What IPs should I whitelist

Answer (score 0):

As the IP's are not provided by Google you are one that should know the addresses and whitelist them. As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-on-prem-howto#securing_outbound_traffic), to do that you should set proper [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).